# Using Well Ordering Principle to Prove Backward Induction of the form $2^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Assume $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that :

$(1)$ : $2^{n}\in \Omega$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

$(2)$ : If $n\in\Omega$ and $\forall n\geq2$, then $n-1\in\Omega$,

My main objective is to :

> Show that $\Omega=\mathbb{N}$

I managed to prove this easily by taking two cases for $\phi(m):=2^{m}$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ one for which $m$ is a power of two and other for which it is not and in both cases it can be inferred that $\phi\in\Omega$.

I now wish to prove this $2^{n}$ variation of induction again but this time I was curious to see how the well ordering principle would work. I shall present my strategy :

**[Strategy]** : We Assume by contradiction that $\Omega$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{N}$. This means that $\mathbb{N}\setminus \Omega\neq\emptyset$ a non empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$, then by the well ordering principle, we have that there exists a least element $p\in\mathbb{N}$. I now thought of achieving  contradiction by proving that $p+n\notin\Omega$ which contradicts the fact that $2^{p}>p\in\Omega$.

> **[Question]** : The method of proving $p+n\notin\Omega$ seems non-trivial to me even though it might turn out to be trivial. I thought of using induction to prove this but I have no clear argument for base case and inductive step.

Any help is much appreciated as I am new and still learning elements of set theory by myself $:)$

Comment: Is your $\Bbb N$ the set of positive integers, or does it include $0$?

Comment: the set $\mathbb{N}$ always starts from $1$.

Comment: Okay; for me, as for many others, it always starts at $0$.

Comment: I shall in that case follow the majority  $:)$

Comment: Unfortunately, both usages are pretty common; I prefer $\Bbb N$ for the non-negative integers and $\Bbb Z^+$ for the positive integers, but there are many variations in use, and sometimes you simply have to ask which version someone is using.

Comment: Indeed, I never got to know why Peano constructed his axioms without including $0$ as the first element of $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a little tricky, and it isn’t $\Bbb N\setminus\Omega$ whose least element you want to use.

If $\Bbb N\setminus\Omega\ne\varnothing$, let $p\in\Bbb N\setminus\Omega$. We know that $n<2^n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so $p<2^p$, and $2^p\in\Omega$ by $(1)$. Let $S=\{n\in\Bbb N:2^p-n\notin\Omega\}$; $2^p-(2^p-p)=p\notin\Omega$, so $2^p-p\in S$, and therefore $S\ne\varnothing$. Let $m=\min S$.

$2^p\in\Omega$, so $2^p-1\in\Omega$ by $(2)$, and therefore $m>1$. But then $m-1\in\Bbb N\setminus S$, so $2^p-m+1=2^p-(m-1)\in\Omega$, and $(2)$ then ensures that $2^p-m=(2^p-m+1)-1\in\Omega$, contradicting the choice of $m$. This contradiction shows that $\Bbb N\setminus\Omega$ cannot be non-empty after all and hence that $\Omega=\Bbb N$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it turned out to be even more trivial than I thought it would be.

Comment: @deerclaysup: You’re very welcome.

Comment: Why is $p+1 \in \Omega$? We only took $p$ to be the least element not in $\Omega$; anything larger than $p$ could go either way.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: Because I made the mistake of responding to two people at once and wasn’t thinking clearly; if the OP will withdraw the acceptance, I’ll delete this nonsense.

Comment: @deerclaysup: My apologies: I had a bad mental hiccup, and the claim that $p+1\in\Omega$ is nonsense, since the induction here is downward. It you’ll remove the acceptance, I’ll delete the answer until I can fix it (or someone posts a proper one).

Comment: It's alright Brian!, I will still think of your approach.

Comment: @deerclaysup: No, to make the argument work, I’d need to know that $p$ was the **largest** member of $\Bbb N\setminus\Omega$.

Comment: @deerclaysup: And I have now completely rewritten it to make it work.

Comment: Thank you once more, it is beautiful and much more rigorous than my previous proof.

Comment: @deerclaysup: You’re welcome. What I did with $S$ is a mildly sneaky way to turn hunting for largest element into hunting for a smallest one, so that one really can appeal to well-ordering.